# I'm trying to change values of the database but it shows SqlException

Tags: c#, sql-server

`@name` is the primary key. `@adress` and `@age` are other columns I want to update data by textboxes but it wont working

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SADDAM\\TESTING;Initial Catalog=testingC#;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand();
    sqlComm = sqlConn.CreateCommand();

    sqlComm.CommandText = @"UPDATE testingd SET name='@name' WHERE adress='@adress',age='@age'";

    sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.Char).Value=textBox1.Text;
    sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@adress", SqlDbType.Char).Value = textBox2.Text;
    sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@age",SqlDbType.Char).Value=textBox3.Text;

    sqlConn.Open();
    sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sqlConn.Close();
}
```

Comment: what is the sql error?

Comment: please post the error...

Answer (score 3):

Take the quotes out of: `UPDATE testingd SET name='@name' WHERE adress='@adress',age='@age'`

and use `and` instead of `,` so that you end up with:

```
UPDATE testingd SET name=@name WHERE adress=@adress and age=@age
```

Comment: now there is no error but it wont update data on table

Comment: run a select against the db with the same where clause - is there a record with address==<address> and age=<age>.  remember - `update` only updates existing data - `insert` inserts a new record.

Comment: i have change the sql command to                                                "UPDATE testingd SET adress=@adress, age=@age where name=@name"   and now its working